# Wire in hole for pins with hole in them?

Tags: soldering

[image: Barrel Jacks]

Looking at two of the three barrel jacks in the graphic, two of them (the upper ones) have holes in their "pins" or "terminals". When soldering to this terminal, should I place the wire through the hole? Or should I line up the wire colinear and parallel to the terminal and solder it that way? Essentially, I mean if the terminal is running vertically, should I also place my unjacketed length of wire vertically?

If the wire should indeed gothrough the hole, do I just place enough wire (a mm or so) into the hole or do I perhaps place in lets say 5 cm, and bend the additional wire back against itself? That is, the unjacketed portion against the jacketed portion?

Comment: you can use crimp-on connectors for these

Comment: on those rounded ones, I like to go through the hole with stripped wire, bending back down like a bobby pin and smooshed with pliers (pin and wire together). I then solder the pin/hole-hugging wire to make a good electrical bond. Then I wrap the wire around the pin above the round end a few turns, like spooling a bobbin, which provides strain relief to the solder joint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're meant to put the wire through the hole and generally you bend a little hook or a zig-zag in it for mechanical strength.

See [this link](https://workmanship.nasa.gov/lib/insp/2%20books/links/sections/613%20Terminals.html) for some terminal soldering guidelines from NASA.

Answer (score 4):

Bending the pre-tinned wire 180° and hooking it through the hole will work properly. It should not be soldered back onto itself, twisted round, or anything like that.

Remember that the solder joint is for electrical contact, and any mechanical support needs to be provided separately.

There are several NASA articles on the subject; here's one with good photos of what is acceptable to them: [NASA Hand Solder Training to NHB 5300.4 (3A-2)](http://www.sal.wisc.edu/docs/Soldering%20Basics.pdf)